# Is there a hotkey to jump between tab groups in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Like when you split a window into two tabs, is there a way to jump between the two (or more) tab groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CTRL 1 - Focus First editor Group

CTRL 2 - Second Editor Group

etc...

You can find more specific shortcuts in the keyboard shortcuts settings, search for `editor group`

[image: switch editor groups]

[image: editor groups]

[Complete list](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_editorwindow-management)